# embedded database hsqldb hibernate persistance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

im trying to persist a blob of size 27Kb to an embedded database (for test purposes) but hibernate is creating the blob field with limit of 255 (e.g. creation sql contains "blob (255)"). Can this be rectified?
Can the default blob size be changed.

I have found a solution with annotations

```
@Column(length=1000000000000000)
...
```

but this is not ideal as file limit must be very large.

I am currently using the spring jdbc embedded database

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="datasource" type="HSQL">
    ...scripts...
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

The default size must be configurable...no?

Comment: No database allows an "infinite" limit for blob (or clob) columns.  The column can be very big (2^63-1 bytes) but that's not infinite. What do you want to store there? The whole internet? And for production applications, don't generate your schema from metadata that hibernate has, as production DB usually require more data (e.g. tablespaces for tables and indexes, etc, etc)

Comment: Just to note: I ran into the same issue with both HSQL and H2 (I think Hibernate has the exact same dialect code for both since I have the exact same issues with both). Setting the column length was the only workaround I could find at the time.

Comment: SOLVED: needed to create a new dialect to override the size parameter